# Cannot run android in react native due to "Could not find com.mg.RxCustomizedImagePicker:fileprovider:1.0.0"

Tags: android, react-native

This is my first time running react native Andriod code, IOS code runs fine, but when I try to run android code, I got this error, what do you suggest I should do?

```
$ react-native run-android

yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-native run-android
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - native-base: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase#readme
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1113 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.mg.RxCustomizedImagePicker:fileprovider:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/Users/XXXlaptop/.m2/repository/com/mg/RxCustomizedImagePicker/fileprovider/1.0.0/fileprovider-1.0.0.pom
       - file:/Users/XXXlaptop/.m2/repository/com/mg/RxCustomizedImagePicker/fileprovider/1.0.0/fileprovider-1.0.0.jar
       - file:/Users/XXXlaptop/Documents/Code/uf-mobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/mg/RxCustomizedImagePicker/fileprovider/1.0.0/fileprovider-1.0.0.pom
       - file:/Users/XXXlaptop/Documents/Code/uf-mobile/node_modules/react-native/android/com/mg/RxCustomizedImagePicker/fileprovider/1.0.0/fileprovider-1.0.0.jar
       - file:/Users/XXXlaptop/Documents/Code/uf-mobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/mg/RxCustomizedImagePicker/fileprovider/1.0.0/fileprovider-1.0.0.pom
       - file:/Users/XXXlaptop/Documents/Code/uf-mobile/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/mg/RxCustomizedImagePicker/fileprovider/1.0.0/fileprovider-1.0.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In root of your project first run :

```
cd android
```

then run :

```
gradlew clean
```

after that , when gradle cleaned project run :

```
cd ..
```

finally run :

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Comment: It didn't work, got the same result, anything else I should try?

Comment: if your react native version is below 0.60 make sure that you link this library correctly